# Polynomial sum: $x^n+x^{n-1}y+x^{n-2}y^2+x^{n-3}y^3+\dots+xy^{n-1}+y^n$

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials, minimal-polynomials

Find sum of the expression,
$$x^n+x^{n-1}y+x^{n-2}y^2+x^{n-3}y^3+\dots+xy^{n-1}+y^n$$
where $x,y$ are real numbers and $n$ is a natural number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:**  It’s a geometric progression with common ratio $\dfrac{y}x$.

Answer (score 3):

It is:
$$\frac{x^{n+1}-y^{n+1}}{x-y}.$$

Comment: A high school identity.